# Connect ionic app (cordova with angularjs) to MS SQL server 2008 database with PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-server-2008, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a project that will require my app to connect to a Microsoft SQL server 2008 database. 
I cannot seem to find a decent walk through or code to help me make this connection. I have tried a few different methods including ajax and PHP .. does any one have a working example I can see or a link to a basic walk through that might help me?

I appreciate any advice people can give

Code below...

Thanks

Thomas

I am trying to use $http to get within my controller:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'app/attendance/index.php' }).success(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response;
});
```

my php looks like this:

```
<?php

$serverName = "myServerName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Mobile_App_Test", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM Attendstu";

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$emparray[] = $row;
}

//write to json file
$fp = fopen('app/attendance/testJson.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

It seems that the controller never enters the php file. I have added a break point to the connection string but it doesn't make it that far.

Has anyone any idea?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a relative url, how about you use your php server's IP address e.g 44.123.22.123/path/to/file.php and see if you get a response, you could test your requests with Postman.